# Custom Apex soap API

Tags: apex, soap-api, webservices, soap, webservicemock

We have written a custom Apex soup API for integrating with ERP System.
Our wsdl works fine .Currently we are accepting the records response one by one sent by ERP.
Now my question is if ERP sends the records in bulk ,then how to consume them.Is it possible in the Wsdl class?

Thanks for the response in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible using collection (List/Array) return type of response class(Most of the cases it is inner class in actual SOAP class) to Invoke/Request method.